# Changing EC2 Instance Type via Powershell

Tags: string, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2

I'm running into what I'm sure is a simple issue I'm overlooking.  I'm trying to change an AWS EC2 InstanceType using the CLI via a Powershell Script.  Everything is running fine up until I go to actually modify the InstanceType.

I've tried multiple different variations and combinations of escape characters to get this to work, but I can't so far.

```
Invoke-Expression 'aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $thisID --instance-type \"{`\"Value`\":`\"m4.large`\"}"'
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the equivalent to this:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-1234567890abcdef0 --instance-type "{\"Value\": \"m1.small\"}"
```

Comment: Running commands external to PowerShell can introduce some issues. Curly braces have special meaning in PowerShell. You will need to escape them in a PowerShell terminal such as:

```'{"Value": "m4.large"}'```. The single quote makes it a string literal.

Comment: As an aside: Don't use `Invoke-Expression` (or any other cmdlet) to synchronously invoke console applications: invoke them _directly_. Specifically, [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, good point on that. Great reference from 2011, but still relevant today! Never ever use ```Invoke-Expression``` outside of PowerShell unless you know exactly what the implications are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [AWS Tools for Powershell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) and use the following command:

`Edit-EC2InstanceAttribute -InstanceId $thisID --InstanceType m4.large`

Documentation Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for the assist @Peter Kay

Comment: You're welcome anytime @JasonWH... good luck with everything!